# Exterior doors giving electrical shocks

Tags: wiring

Recently my front and back door started shocking me when I touched it. Also I plugged my camper up to my homes outside outlet and the camper door would shock me too. We are always having light bulbs go out. What could be the problem?

Comment: Wow. That's serious as they should naturally be isolated from both electrical and plumbing. From what I've read here I'd suspect a problem with the service. Do you have wood or steel framing? I'd call the power company right away and ask about an open neutral.

Comment: I agree this sounds dangerous.

Comment: @isherwood I think your comment is an answer and one that needs permanence (comments can disappear).

Comment: I'm not an electrician and wasn't that confident in my advice. Anyone more qualified is welcome to run with it.